Output voltage decreases when load is removed in LM317T Voltage Regulator Circuit
I'm experiencing an issue with my LM317T voltage regulator circuit:

All the caps here are electrolytic, except for the 100 nF ones, they are these small SMD ones.
The circuit is designed to provide an adjustable output voltage. The input is 12V and the output is 8 V. I am facing the following issue:

First, I set the potentiometer so that I have 8 V (now the adjustment pin is at 6.8 V). Then I connect my load, and it draws around 400 mA. When I disconnect the load, the voltage drops to 7.2 V (and the adjustment pin voltage drops to 6.2 V).
In order to get 8 V again, I have to connect the load OR disconnect the 12 V supply and connect it again.

What could be happening? I double-checked every component and all seem to be OK.
This is my PCB layout. Please note that the 10 μF in the adj pin is externally soldered on the PCB, and that D3 is now attached to the adj pin. I did this externally like this because the previous design (PCB photo) had oscillations.


Is this on a breadboard or PCB? Can you show your layout/connections?

How long you drive the 400mA load? It will cause the regulator to dissipate 1.6W while the load is connected. Does the regulator heat up beyond being able to touch it? Which exact regulator you bough in which package, and do you have a heat sink?

@Justme It happens even if I drive it for only half a second to half an hour.

@SamGibson Thank you. I didn't know I could edit my post.

@JohnD The PCB is in the post now

The layout isn't great.  Have you looked at the output on a scope to be sure the part is stable?  For a good layout look at the examples here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1723063353308&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Flm117

@ahmed You did not answer all the important questions which exact chip model from which exact manufacturer it is. However the PCB layout does not look very good, the 100nF caps are near regulator but they share a long narrow ground path to the electrolytic. At least you can remove the C7 on adj pin but the PCB does not seem to have C7. Also the PCB does not seem to match the schematic on many other parts too - is D3 between GND and OUT?

@ahmed - Hi, Re: "I didn't know I could edit my post" Oh! Welcome to Stack Exchange :) Several things here are different from typical forums. Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. Questions can be edited to improve them, as long as the edit doesn't invalidate an existing genuine answer attempt. There's a long FAQ which will help you to understand how to use the site, to get the best out of it. If you need help with the site rules & etiquette, you can ask on our [meta] (or in [chat], when you have 20 points).

@ahmed as long as Vin is 10.5 Vmin , your result is an anomaly

@JohnD Thank you for the example. Could that be causing the issue?

@Justme It is LM317T from ST. As for the PCB, yes it doesn't match. As mentioned in the post, my PCB had an oscillation issue, so I am connecting C7 off the PCB and taking the diode off the ground and connecting it to the adj pin.

@D.A.S. Vin is 12 Volts.

Hard to say if the PCB layout is the issue; if it's causing instability at no load you should be able to see that on a scope.  If the output is stable and just shifted down it might not be the layout.

@JohnD It is stable but shifted down. I also noticed that my circuit has a lot of spikes on the input line (power supply). If I disconnect my circuit, there is no spikes.

I connected the whole circuit on a breadboard and it works great, no load effects and the supply doesn't have spikes now. I wonder then if it is the PCB.

So what is the difference? the load? the rest of the PCB. No-load does not seem to be relevant.  Can you describe more?

@D.A.S. The rest of the PCB is just another variable power supply module and a transimpedance amplifier that are powered from the 12V power supply.

Define or show the spikes, frequency , amplitude, load dependent?

Hi @D.A.S., I removed all the caps, it works great now

The LM317 requires a minimum output current to be within spec.
According to the datasheet for ST's LM317, the minimum load current should be set to at least 10 mA to deal with the worst case requirement. (That is the maximum minimum load current).

The maximum current through the ADJ pin is 100 uA, so in the OP's circuit, when the load is disconnected virtually all of the required 10 mA must flow through R2 and RV1.
The setting of RV1 required to get an 8V output is
$$\text{RV1} \approx \text{R2}\left(\frac{V_{out}}{V_{ref}}-1\right)$$
The total resistance from Vout to ground via R2 and RV1 is
$$\text{R_T} = \text{R2}+\text{RV1} \approx\text{R2}\frac{V_{out}}{V_{ref}}$$
Using the values of Vout = 8V and R2 = \$240\Omega\$, we get
$$\text{R_T} \approx 240 \frac{8}{1.25} \approx 1536\Omega$$
Which gives us an Iout of
$$I_{out} \approx \frac{8}{1536} \approx 5\; \text{mA}$$
which may work in some cases, but which is below the maximum limit for the minimum load current.
You can add a resistor between the circuit's Vout and ground to ensure that there is enough load current. If you always want the output to be 8 V, then a 1.5 k\$\Omega\$ resistor would do. However, if you intend to vary the output voltage, the resistor value would need to be chosen to ensure 10 mA load current under all conditions.


It does. The RV must be about 1300 ohms for 8V output. And there is also the 240 ohm resistor to output, along with the diode. 2. No it does not, the minimum is 5mA or 10mA depending on exact regulator type, and the 240 ohm resistor will provide the 5mA load.


@Justme oops. Thanks for the catch. The datasheet says typical minimum load is 5 mA, and max minimum load is 10 mA. I didn't want to confuse with max minimum load. If one designs for worst case, that would be 10 mA. No?

The minimum load depends on exact regulator type and manufacturer. It could be stable with 5mA or stable with 10mA, so if unknown it might be sensible to use 10mA with 120 ohm resistance. The regulator might also just overheat with 1.6W dissipation when load is connected,

@Justme are you sure you are not confusing the table for the LM217 as a "type" of LM317?

Yes, I am sure I am not confusing between LM217 and LM317, but might be confusing between different LM317 types such as LM317T and LM317L.

As others mentioned, I think there is already more than 5mA output through R2.

The usual we I get datasheets is with a seach such as "mouser LM317T". It brings up this page. With a few clicks I get to https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/LM317T?qs=swDD%252BF%252Bps7c8uLyY%252B3mJJw%3D%3D. Which brings me to the datasheet I linked in my answer. The linked datasheet gives only a typical and a max minimum load current as far as I can tell. The table says LM317, but the end of the datasheet says LM317T. I don't know where you are getting your information.

I recall the LM317 was always reliable with no load, such as the CC limiter for the Vo-Vadj and while the minimum load is 3.5 typ, 10 mA max this refers to specs tests as a regulated source with no pull-down control except by a passive load with thermal shutdown.

I connected the whole circuit on a breadboard and it works great, no load effects and the supply doesn't have spikes now. I wonder then if it is the PCB.
